# Data cursor on a line plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am new to python and am looking for a similar feature found in MATLAB. Its called data cursors in signal processing toolbox and I want to use a pre-existing or build a similar one.

[image]

The idea is to get a data line which when moved with a mouse and shows the data point of the plotted graph. Linked with the x-axis of the other subplots we can see the data matching of other graphs too.

Is this achievable in python?

Comment: It's definitely possible to write something like this using Python. What have you tried so far? What problems did you run into? If you're looking for a library that just does the whole thing out of the box, you'll probably have more trouble (and may as well use Matlab, I suppose)

Comment: E.g. [Add cursor to matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679473/add-cursor-to-matplotlib) and [How to have a fast crosshair mouse cursor for subplots in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63195460/how-to-have-a-fast-crosshair-mouse-cursor-for-subplots-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @Grismar I haven't tried anything yet. I am not able to understand how to start. As I am new, I did lots of searches on the internet but couldn't find an answer. What is the concept behind these data cursors? Does it mean that the graphs constantly update itself when I move the cursor?

Comment: @JohanC Thanks Johan. It's somewhat similar. My question is relatable to this thread. I want to see the data on the plotted line only and the marker should be movable.