# I have a plot imbedded in my GUI and I want to add a cursor to display the x and y coordinates as I hover over the plot

Tags: python, tkinter

Plot displaying properly

```
x=[]
y=[]    
figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100) 
plot = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
figure.suptitle(Date, fontsize=12)
plot.plot(x, y, color="blue")
cursor = Cursor(plot,horizOn=True,vertOn=False,color="green",linewidth=2.0)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, root)                    
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=3,columnspan=4,pady = 4, padx=4)
```

cursor = Cursor() takes ax and it seems i cant put plot.axes

Comment: You can bind the canvas and get x, y coordinates using event.x and event.y

Comment: `Cursor` is for having a crosshair where your cursor currently is. For having a crosshair to the closest data point from your cursor and displaying the coordinates, you need a mouse event where you get the x/y coordinates of your mouse and then figure out what the closest data point in your graph is to set your vertical/horizontal lines + text. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679473/add-cursor-to-matplotlib) for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the `Cursor` instance after creating the canvas:

```
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=3,columnspan=4,pady = 4, padx=4)

cursor = Cursor(plot, horizOn=True, vertOn=False, color="green", linewidth=2.0)
```

---

Full example code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor

Date = "2021-06-01"

root = tk.Tk()

x = []
y = []

figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
plot = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
#print(plot)
figure.suptitle(Date, fontsize=12)
plot.plot(x, y, color="blue")

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=3,columnspan=4,pady = 4, padx=4)

# pack_toolbar=False will make it easier to use a layout manager later on.
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root, pack_toolbar=False)
toolbar.update()
toolbar.grid(sticky="ew")

cursor = Cursor(plot, useblit=True, horizOn=True, vertOn=True, color="green", linewidth=2.0)

root.mainloop()
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: I tried it and did not work, because I don't know if Cursor(plot,...) is correct or not. every documentation is using Cursor(ax,...) where ax are the axes

Comment: @Joe_bart It works for me.  Note that `plot` is of type `AxesSubplot`.  You can use `print(plot)` to verify it.

Comment: correct print(plot) gives me AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77), but still no sign of cursor when i run the GUI

Comment: I can see a horizontal green line following the cursor when hover on the plot.

Comment: weird. Is the plot in the GUI? or outside on a separate window? it works if its outside of the GUI like a new window, but inside still not working

Comment: My code is based on yours and yours is embedded inside a tkinter window.

Comment: @Joe_bart I have posted my example as reference.

Comment: just tried your code it works! I think my issue is that my data is too large because on small data it's working very fine.

Comment: or maybe even my grid layout is the issue